Garage Man Door Replacement Questions
I need to install a new man door into my garage. Here is the current setup:


Here is a drawing of what is there if you took off all the sheet rock and in case it's hard to tell in the pics:

Looks like they created a DIY door jamb and added a slab door. I want to put in a prehung door but in order to do so I need to shorten the cripples a few inches and move the top frame piece (just above the top jamb piece) up a little bit. So here are my questions:
1). As long as the big header piece is supported by jack studs can I do this without bringing the whole house down on top of me?
2). The side jamb pieces each have 2 bolts through them. Any ideas as to why that would be?

3). Can I remove the DIY jamb? Does it look like it's structural or holding weight such that if I took them out I'd have problems?
I hope that all makes sense. If not, let me know and I can try to clarify. Here's some more pictures of the header and studs in case that helps. Thanks in advance for any ideas or help you all give me.




Location might matter for the bolts.  If that is a gable end, then there is less load than the sides, so your plan seems good.

at time of construction possibly bolts were available in longer length than screws and with a 7" wall assembly maybe jack/king stud for door not in plane of door extension.  I'd remove and not worry about anything falling down.

Maybe the bolts connect tha garage frame to the house frame  it's hard to tell.
